# ExitCodeException on Yarn containers

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm having the following exception when running a simple YARN application, how I could get more information to debug the problem?

```
Oct 14, 2014 12:29:19 PM dz.lab.yarn.simple.handler.RMCallbackHandler onContainersCompleted
INFO: container 'container_1410790353365_0036_02_000002' status is ContainerStatus: [ContainerId: container_1410790353365_0036_02_000002, State: COMPLETE, Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's

Comment: I'm getting the same exception. In my case it is caused because I exceeded my disk quota. You can see that in the log of a failed reducer task.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, its frustrating to debug such problems. In my case, after looking in the log file (found with `find / -name log_filename`) of the failing container I found that there was an internal exception caused by the program running on this container!

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information from the container's logs.

You can see the container's logs next ways:

1. From RM's UI (http://_rm_hostname_>:8088). More details here:
   http://hadooptutorial.info/tracing-logs-through-yarn-web-ui/
2. Via console command: "yarn logs -applicationId "
3. Manually find the logs under next locations:

a) If aggregation is disabled (logs will be located in local directory, where your container was run):
$HADOOP_HOME$/logs/userlogs/application_1490965385045_0002/

b) If aggregation is enabled (logs will be located in HDFS):
/tmp/logs/*username*>/logs/application_1490965385045_0002/_node_name_>